# Improve S3 image uploads

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I have thousands of image upload to s3. I want to know the best way to do. I use the ruby gem "aws/s3", but it seems not to upload asynchronously. Should i use threads to do? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use transmit for ftp and they have a connector to s3. You might try that for uploading large numbers of files.

Comment: Cyberduck also handles S3 transfers and is available on OS X and Windows.

Comment: could you give me the link, never seen that before?

Comment: @Chanmap - http://www.panic.com/transmit/ Transmit costs money. Cyberduck is free. I'm sure a lot of ftp clients provide access to S3 now.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sample (Rails) project using a Flash/Silverlight object to upload directly to S3 (i.e. asynchronously so it doesn't tie up your server) that you can take a look at.  Once Amazon allows HTML5 uploads, it also supports that.

https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-Plupload